# Getting props through HOC when mounting in Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test some code that uses firebase. I am implementing the firebase-mock library. The problem I'am encountering now is that most all the components I should test get the firebase instance from a HOC (I have a class with the firebase methods I am using that is provided through the context API in the index.js and consumed via a withFirebase HOC, the wrapped component will have firebase in its props).

In this case the code I am trying to test is the following:

```
// mount.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withFirebase } from '../../components/Firebase';

class mount extends Component {
  state = {
    data: null,
  };

  ref = this.props.firebase.db.ref('/testing');

  componentDidMount() {
    // Fetch from testing ref

    this.ref.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({ data: snap });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.ref.off('value');
  }

  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}

export default withFirebase(mount);
```

In my test file I'm doing the following:

```
describe('Component mount.js', () => {
  it.only('fetches', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Mount />);
    console.log(wrapper.prop());
    console.log(wrapper.state().data);
  });
});
```

This fails because this.props.firebase is null.
How could I solve this so that I can continue and finally mock firebase calls as i was intending.
I'm guessing that the problem is how to use the Context API in Enzyme, but I'm not sure.

Comment: One option is to export your unwrapped component so you can pass a firebase mock to it directly in your tests.  (that is the approach often used to [test redux HOC-connected components](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components))

Answer (score 0):

The message you are getting is because enzyme.mount() is returning the withFirebase HOCcomponent, not the <Mount> component that you expect. what you need to do is "find" the contained component. In your example I think `myContainedComponent = wrapper.find('Mount')` would return the component that you could then do `console.log(myContainedComponet.props);`  There are a lot of answers to similar questions about using Enzyme to test HOC and their enclosed components. I am using React 17 which is not supported by Enzyme.mount() so I have to use shallow. Again there are answers related to doing  `wrapper = shallow(shallow(<BurgerBuilder/>).get(0));` but these don't work for my setup either.

What is working for me is:

```
wrapper = shallow(<BurgerBuilder/>);
instance = wrapper.find('BurgerBuilder').dive().instance();
jest.spyOn(instance, 'addIngredientHandler');
```

NOTE: this is the export for the BurgerBuilder component.

```
export default withErrorHandler(BurgerBuilder, axiosOrders);
```

In this example, instance holds the class instance of the contained component rather than the HOC, withErrorHandler.

One of the interesting things about my example is that 'addIngredientHandler' is an arrow function in my class. There are other threads that talk about the complexities of [testing class member arrow functions in React](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/365). (BTW, you do not need to do `instance.forceUpdate();` )

In the interest of full disclosure, I am building my testing skills as I learn React. The components I am testing were developed while running through the Udemy course: [React - The Complete Guide (incl Hooks, React Router, Redux)](https://www.udemy.com/course-dashboard-redirect/?course_id=1362070)